# imacros for firefox not creating delimiter

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, imacros

I'm using imacros for firefox to take advantage of using  javascript. However the CSV file created has no delimiters, making it difficult for me to import into a program like MS Excel. How do I get it to add a delimiter to ease my work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not normal... can you provide us with example code; there is also settings which I found here.

http://wiki.imacros.net/index.php?search=firefox+delimiter&title=Special%3ASearch

Comment: Thanks thought as much